# Behavior of Ortho- and Para-hydrogen in a Magnetic Field

Tags: quantum-spin, hydrogen

At low enough temperature, at equillbrium, the dihydrogen molecule is predominately [parahydrogen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spin_isomers_of_hydrogen), with the spins of the two protons opposite.  Does an external magnetic field alter the ortho-para equillbrium?

Answer (score 2):

I seem to have found an answer in the reference [On the Variation of Ortho-hydrogen and Para-hydrogen Ratio with Magnetic Field Strength at Low Temperature](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs10909-011-0346-0).  At high enough field strength, orthohydrogen rather than parahydrogen is favored.

Answer (score 0):

Your own reference makes it very clear that a magnetic field **affects** the ortho-para equilibrium.  A magnetic field acts as **a catalyst** to facilitate the conversion of orthohydrogen to parahydrogen, as the temperature of the dihydrogen is decreased.

Comment: A catalyst increases the rate at which equilibrium is approached, but doesn't alter the equilibrium constant. I would like to know whether placing hydrogen in a magnetic field changes the ratio between ortho and para hydrogen at equilibrium.  In other words does the magnetic field favor orthohydrogen or parahydrogen, and if so how and why?